# Comparing different linear convolution methods in Matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

I'm trying to understand the difference between linear and circular convolution by adapting the Matlab methodologies [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/linear-and-circular-convolution.html). I'm comparing the results of linear convolution with use of the inbuilt [`conv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) and [`cconv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cconv.html) function, Bruno Luong's [`convnfft`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24504-fft-based-convolution), and NAG's [`c06pk`](http://www.nag.com/numeric/mb/manual64_24_1/html/C06/c06pkf.html).

This is related to the [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39493/convolution-dfts-how-much-zero-padding-is-necessary-to-avoid-circular-convolu) post.

My code is

```
% complex vectors
x = rand(2^5,1) + 1j*rand(2^5,1);
y = rand(2^5,1) - 1j*rand(2^5,1);

clin = conv(x,y); % Matlab convolution function
cfun = convnfft(x,y); % Bruno Luong function

N = length(x)+length(y)-1;
xpad = [x' zeros(1,N-length(x))]; % pad vectors
ypad = [y' zeros(1,N-length(y))];
ccirc = cconv(xpad,ypad); % do linear convolution with circular convolution function
cnag = c06pk(int64(1),xpad,ypad); % do linear convolution with NAG function

figure()
plot(clin,'o'); hold on; plot(cfun,'+')
figure()
plot(ccirc,'.'); hold on; plot(cnag,'x')
```

When I plot the results of linear convolution using the various methods outlined in the code, not all of them agree with the `clin` result. The `cfun` agrees, but `ccirc` and `cnag` don't because they are designed for finding circular convolutions.

Have I done something wrong with the zero-padding?

**Edit:** If I plot the results of these linear convolutions I get:

[image] [image]

Is there some scaling issue in `cconv` and `c06pk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
xpad = [x' zeros(1,N-length(x))]; 
ypad = [y' zeros(1,N-length(x))];
```

However, the `'` operator, does not only transpose but also conjugate. Replace it by

```
xpad = [x.' zeros(1,N-length(x))]; 
ypad = [y.' zeros(1,N-length(x))];
```

This should fix the problem. I could only test `conv` and `cconv` which after this fix agreed perfectly.